# How to free space in Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

My Elasticsearch cluster status is red due to low space but when I checked through query `GET /_cat/allocation?v&pretty` it's showing  6.8 Gb free space in both nodes.

Can anyone help me?

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host          ip            node
     6       25.5gb    27.3gb      6.8gb     34.2gb           80 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x 
     6       25.5gb    27.3gb      6.8gb     34.2gb           80 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
```

Comment: I think watermark threshold is set to 80%

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the disk watermark as mentioned in the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html)

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings" -d '{ 
"transient": {
  "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "1gb",
  "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "500mb",
  "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "200mb",
  "cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"
}'
```